# WordPress - Check slug availability

Tags: wordpress, slug

How can I check if a slug already exists in my WordPress database?

I'd like to check any slug (post, page, taxonomies and custom post type/taxonomies)

thanks

Comment: use `wp_unique_post_slug()` for unique slug...
if Your slug is exist than, this function will give you new slug with suffix (-2, -3, -4...)...

Comment: Darn! Saw this now after i posted.

Comment: @AkshayPaghdar it checks all slugs (page, cpt...) or only post slugs? thx

Comment: Full Function parameters is like this:-
`wp_unique_post_slug( $slug, $post_ID, $post_status, $post_type, $post_parent )`
So you can provide post_type in this function...

Comment: Good method **http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/207978/33667**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_unique_post_slug has the answer. If you use it giving it the desired slug, it will return one that truly is unique.

Answer (score 1):

I just answered this over here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/25940/how-to-check-if-a-slug-exists/144439#144439

Not sure what the policy on duplicate answers is, but here you go:

```
function the_slug_exists($post_name) {
    global $wpdb;
    if($wpdb->get_row("SELECT post_name FROM wp_posts WHERE post_name = '" . $post_name . "'", 'ARRAY_A')) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

You can then use it like this:

```
    if (the_slug_exists('contact')) {
            // do something
    }
```

Replace "contact" with whatever slug you want to test for.

Comment: Only works on default installs with the wp_ prefix not changed, as you should have. This will work: `if($wpdb->get_row("SELECT post_name FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."posts WHERE post_name = '" . $post_name . "'", 'ARRAY_A')) {...`

Answer (score 0):

Use [WP_Query()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query):

```
$args = array(
  'post_type'    => 'custom-post-type',
  'name' => 'my-new-slug'
);

$query = new WP_Query($args);

if ($query->post_count == 0) {
  // I am unique!
}
```

In general, `WP_Query()` prevents the need for direct DB calls and makes your site more maintainable.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
    $url = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    $isItYourSlug = strpos($url, 'your_slug');

    if ($isItYourSlug!==false) {
        Do Something
    }
?>
```

It ok? It work for me!